# Cannot find module {applicationPath}

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I am trying to run an application in debug mode from Visual Studio code. When I click debug following error occurs:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\electron2\electron_app\--inspect-brk=15965'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\electron2\electron_app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at init (C:\electron2\electron_app\node_modules\electron-compile\lib\config-parser.js:294:16)
    at main (C:\electron2\electron_app\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\lib\es6-init.js:58:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\electron2\electron_app\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\lib\es6-init.js:61:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\electron2\electron_app\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\lib\es6-init.js:63:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
```

My debug configuration looks like  this

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Debug",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
        "windows": {
          "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
        },
        "args" : ["."]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Also one more error caught:

```
No such module: atom_browser_features
```

Never heard of such module before.

Used to work before, but all of sudden it stopped to work. Anyone has a clue what the problem might be?

Comment: Seeing the same thing, looks like a bug they might have introduced in v3.0.x. Consider creating an issue on [their github](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues). Notable how nothing even comes up if googling for "atom_browser_features", besides this q.

Comment: Looks like `--inspect-brk=15965` is somehow being interpreted as the "main" script. It would be useful to see the command that VSCode generates to run electron under the debugger.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger, in my case the command is defined in `launch.json` (which I copied from [this VSCode recipe](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron)) and it is `"${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"`

Comment: The first line of output to the "Debug Console" view is the command I'm referencing. Using the [`electron-quick-start`](https://github.com/octref/vscode-electron-debug/tree/master/electron-quick-start) project I get the following command `G:\Development\vscode-electron-debug\electron-quick-start/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd --inspect-brk=32785 main.js` when I run the "Debug Main Process" configuration. I have no problems running the quick start app under `electron@3.0.8` either, so the problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger that'd be `C:/test/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd --remote-debugging-port=9223 . --inspect-brk=47365`. **Upgrading to v3.0.8 seems to have fixed the issue, thanks!**. You should still see those errors if you tick `All Exceptions` in Debug View (F1, "Focus on Breakpoints View"), then start debugging, but they no longer break the rest of the debugging session for me. I assume they are safe to ignore because they are 1st chance exceptions which are getting caught later. Feel free to post an answer to grab the bounty :)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger oh and pass my best regards to Igor as a proof of the six degrees of separation )

Comment: No problem. You know Igor, eh? Small world :) will do!

Comment: Do you have electron-prebuilt-compile in your devDependencies? Do you really need it? Try to remove it: Delete the line, delete node_modules and package-lock.json and do a fresh npm install.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely having issues because `--inspect-brk=15965` is being interpreted as the "main" script.

Assuming the command line is generated similar to noseratio's:

```
C:/test/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd --remote-debugging-port=9223 . --inspect-brk=47365
```

You can see that `--inspect-brk` comes after the declared args, however, node arguments must be declared prior to the "main" script. You can try upgrading to `electron@3.0.8` to see if the issue resolves itself. Alternatively, you could attempt to be more explicit with the entry point like they have done in the [`electron-quick-start`](https://github.com/octref/vscode-electron-debug/tree/master/electron-quick-start) project.

```
{
    "name": "Debug Main Process",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
    "windows": {
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
    },
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
    "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I tried (electron upgrade + configuration change), but unfortunately it does not help. It is also not possible to run the application via command line. The error I get there is for line: `const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app;` is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron" use "{workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\.bin\\electron" in runtimeexecutable and windows:{runtimeexecutable} as you're using windows I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, but did not help.